# Efeito sombra igual na tela de login do gmail

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Como fazer para o mesmo efeito de sombra ao clicar sobre o botão de mostrar/ocultar senha igual tem na tela de [login](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/sl/pwd?hl=pt-BR&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin) do Google.

Já tem tentei fazer com o pseudo-elemento *:before* usando *:focus* mas não obtive sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
const btn_password = $(".viewPassword .verSenha");
const input_password = $(".viewPassword input");
btn_password.on('click', function() {
  let type = input_password.attr("type");
  if (type == 'password') {
    input_password.prop('type', 'text');
  }
  if (type == 'text') {
    input_password.prop('type', 'password');
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('ic-visibility-off ic-visibility-on');
  if ($(this).hasClass('ic-visibility-off')) {
    $(this).attr('title', 'Mostrar senha');
  } else {
    $(this).attr('title', 'Ocultar senha');
  }

});
```

```css
.input {
  width: 270px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-control {
  background-color: #f9fafa;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.64;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #4e5159;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 13px 40px 13px 14px;
  border: solid 1px #f3f5f5;
}

.icon-svg {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.ic-visibility-off {
  width: 18.3px;
  height: 15.8px;
  background-image: url('https://webmachado.com.br/assets/svg/ic-visibility-off.svg');
}

.ic-visibility-on {
  width: 18.3px;
  height: 15.8px;
  background-image: url('https://webmachado.com.br/assets/svg/ic-visibility-on.svg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="input viewPassword">
    <i class="icon-svg ic-password"></i>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" placeholder="Senha">
    <i class="icon-svg verSenha ic-visibility-off" title="Mostrar senha"></i>
  </div>
```

Comment: Vc se refere a essa sombre envolta do olho quando clica nele? http://prntscr.com/lr6yi1

Comment: isso mesmo, também queria conseguir replicar este efeito da borda do input, mas por hora só do botão mesmo

Comment: Cara bolei uma resposta e deixei os detalhes lá qq coisa é só perguntar. Sobre essa linha abaixo do input realmente seria interessante vc abrir outra pergunta, ou até dar uma pesquisadinha aqui no site pq acho que já vi exemplos disso por aqui

Answer (score 2):

A minha ideia aqui é usar a *pseudo-classe* `:active` para ativar a animação do elemento apenas no clique. Segundo a Mozilla veja que não é apenas a tag `<a>` ou `<button>` que pode o `:active`, na verdade até uma tag `<h1>` ou `<p>` pode receber essa *pseudo-classe*

> The `:active` *pseudo-class* is also typically matched when using the keyboard *tab* key. It is frequently used on `<a>` and `<button>` HTML elements, **but may not be limited to just those**.

**PORTUGUÊS**
"A *pseudo-classe* `:active` também é normalmente usada quando se usa a tecla *tab* do teclado. É freqüentemente usado em elementos HTML `<a>` e `<button>`, **mas pode não estar limitado apenas a eles**."

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:active

---

Agora vamos ao que interessa.

Como disse o `:active` pode ser usado em vário elementos, então eu usei uma `<label>` com um `for` para acionar um `checkbox` que dependendo do estado `:checked` ou não vai trocar o ícone do "botão". Já com o `:active` eu vou disparar a animação sempre que o elemento for clicado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro da `label` eu tenho dois ícones, um fica escondido e o outro aparecendo, quando eu mudo o `checkbox` para `:checked` eu escondo o ícone que estava visível e oculto o que já estava aparecendo.

**Veja o código do modelo da imagem:**

```css
label {
 margin: 40px;
 height: 24px;
 width: 24px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 user-select: none;
}
label:active::before {
 content: "";
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 filter: blur(5px);
 animation: anima 250ms forwards linear;
}
@keyframes anima {
 50% {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
 }
}

input:checked + label i.sim{
 display: block !important;
}
input:checked + label i.nao{
 display: none;
}
.sim {
 display: none !important;
}
.nao {
 bottom: block;
}
input {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<input type="checkbox" name="" id="efeito">
<label for="efeito" class="btnx">
  <i class="material-icons sim">visibility</i>
  <i class="material-icons nao">visibility_off</i>
</label>
```